# facebook-sdk-0.4.0 is compatible with python 33 ? what facebook-sdk i have to use with python 33?

Tags: facebook, python-3.x

Is facebook-sdk-0.4.0 compatible with python33 ?

I try it All and didn´t work them try the same process in python 27 and it works.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please explain what kind of errors you've got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The released Python Facebook API module does not support Python 3. You can tell this by looking at the source code, where you'll see several things that are no longer allowed  (such as `assert` statements).

However, it appears that there are a few different forks that have been ported to work on Python 3, some of which are also backwards compatible to Python 2. [Here's one](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/pull/84) that I found in a quick search (I've not tried it myself, so it may have bugs or other issues).